# How to fix "Missing a temporary folder" error in Wordpress?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, php, error, permissions

Today I pushed to live (using Softaculous) a staged version of my WordPress website which was working perfectly. Afterwards, the only thing that doesn't work properly is uploading files/media.

The error I get is "Missing a temporary folder."

Now, I made good use of the internet and went on quite a lot of websites which detailed a few steps to fixing this, but to no success. Whatever I do, the error persists.

The "fixes" i tried so far are as follows:

a. Define temp folder in **wp-config.php**

1.
 `define(‘WP_TEMP_DIR’, ‘/wp-content/temp/’);`

2.
`define(‘WP_TEMP_DIR’, dirname(__FILE__) . ‘/wp-content/temp/’);`

3.
 `define('WP_TEMP_DIR',ABSPATH.'/temp/');`

b. Define temp folder in the **php.ini** file

1.`upload_tmp_dir= ABSPATH.'/temp/'`

2.`upload_tmp_dir= /home/user/public_html/temp/`

c. Change folder permission from the default 755

1. tried 775
2. tried 777

I also checked the functions.php file for the function to make sure nothing is broken, but it is all fine as far as I can tell and can't find a reason why it doesn't execute as it should.

What other methods should I try without having to reinstall the whole website (for obvious reasons)?

Comment: "`define(‘WP_TEMP_DIR’, ‘/wp-content/temp/’);`" - You are using curly quotes here - presumably that is just a "typo" in your question? Where were you able to edit `php.ini`? Unless this is your own server, you probably don't have access to `php.ini`? You would then need to restart your webserver (Apache?).

Comment: @DocRoot Yes, that is a typo in my question. In my files I was using the proper character.
In regards to the `php.ini` file, I was editing it in the **public_html** folder. For safe measure I also dropped a copy of the file in the **wp-admin** folder (though I think it is useless, but I was close to desperate).

Comment: `php.ini` is not ordinarily a per-directory config file that's permitted in user-space, unless your host has specifically enabled this. To change local config options you need to either use `.htaccess` (ie. `php_value` or `php_flag` directives) or use a `.user.ini` file (same syntax as `php.ini`) in your HTML directory. Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php

Answer (score 2):

Well... I fixed it! But as it usually goes, I'm unsure of the exact thing that put it together. However, I will leave what I did over here, in hopes that it might help someone else in the future.

From cPanel, I first changed my php version from 7.2 to 7.1. And it crashed my website.
Therefore, I changed it back to 7.2, and voila!

It simply works.